# Approximation of an integral involving x and 1-x

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximation

I am looking for an approximation of the integral

$F(k,R)=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(Rx)^{-2}+(1-x)^{-k}}$,

that is valid to within 1% over the range $2<k<10$ and $R>1$. Is there a standard approach to problems like this?

This integral came about in a research problem where I am trying to smoothly connect the functions $x^{2}$ and $(1-x)^{k}$. If someone can provide an approximation (or a closed form solution!) I'll gladly acknowledge them in the research paper this result is needed for.

Comment: is $k$ an integer or any real number?

Comment: Both $k$ and $R$ can take real values. Sorry for not specifying that!

Comment: Mathematica finds a closed form solution in form of a Gamma - Function: F(k,R)= 2*R^2*Gamma(1+k)/Gamma(4+k) valid for Re(k)>-1

Comment: That solution doesn't seem to match the result I get numerically. What command did you give Mathematica?

Comment: Can you use the beta function here?

Comment: I was busy so I just typed in the integral you posted and respond the result. One needs to compare Integrate and NIntegrate and your numerical method, I do not know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was to use Gauss-Laguerre quadrature, with an order 10 scheme being sufficient to achieve the accuracy I required.